# jquery addClass() transition bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-transitions

UPDATE: The problem seems to be the transition between `height:13em` and `height:auto`. When I change them both to `em` or both to pixels, it works fine.

I'm using a simple jquery function to add and remove a class and have a transition set up. The transition is acting strange. It doesn't work in FF and Safari and Chrome give a strange transition effect by collapsing the height, then opening it to it's predefined css height.

http://jsfiddle.net/k8gfb/7/

HTML

```
<div id="site-description-extended" class="site-description-extended">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima. Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.
</div>

<div id="view-more-button" class="view-more-button">    
  <a href="#">
    Click for More
  </a>
</div>

<div id="view-less-button" class="view-less-button">    
  <a href="#">
     Click for Less
  </a>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
     $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".view-more-button").click(function () {
            $(".site-description-extended").addClass("extend-description");
            $(".view-more-button").hide();
            $(".view-less-button").show();
        });
    });
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".view-less-button").click(function () {
            $(".site-description-extended").removeClass("extend-description");
            $(".view-more-button").show();
            $(".view-less-button").hide();
        });
    });
```

CSS

```
    .site-description-extended {
        background: url(images/separator-horizontal.png) center bottom no-repeat;
        box-sizing: border-box;
            -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            -o-box-sizing: border-box;
            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        clear: both;
        float: left;
        font-size: 12px;
        line-height: 22px;
        padding: 0px 160px 29px;
        text-align: left;
        width: 100%;
        height:12em;
        overflow:hidden;
        transition: all 1s ease;
        -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
        -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
        -o-transition: all 1s ease;
        }
    .view-more-button {
        text-align:center;
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
        font-size:0.8em;
        text-decoration:none;
    }
    .view-less-button{
        text-align:center;
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
        font-size:0.8em;
        text-decoration:none;
        display:none;
    }
    a, a:hover, a:active, a:visited {
        text-decoration:none;
    }
    .extend-description {
        height:auto !important;
    }
```

Comment: Why not create just one button and `toggleClass`?

Comment: I'll try it and see if it effects the transition at all.

Comment: still having the same effect on the transition...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/k8gfb/10/

Comment: I think the problem may be that I'm passing the transition from `height:13em` to `height:auto`, because when I change them both to pixels, I don't have any problems. http://jsfiddle.net/k8gfb/11/

Comment: You can't animate to an attribute `auto`. You could calculate what auto would be and animate to that pixel though